# jQuery - Click event on div but not on checkbox in the div

Tags: jquery, checkbox, click

I'm trying to setup a click event on a div, and I would like that event to fire if that div is clicked anywhere except a checkbox in the div.  If the checkbox is clicked, I do not want the div's click event to fire.  I setup a click event on the checkbox and returned false, which stops the div's click event, but does not allow the checkbox to become checked either.  Here's what I have now:

```
$('.theDiv').click(function() {
    // Click event for the div, I'm slide toggling something
    $('.sub-div', $(this)).slideToggle();
});

$('.checkboxInTheDiv').click(function() {
    // Do stuff for the checkbox click, but dont fire event above
    return false; // returning false won't check/uncheck the box when clicked
})
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Instead of returning false, which prevents the default action, try just stopping propagation.

```
$('.checkboxInTheDiv').click( function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    ... other stuff...
    return true;
});
```

Comment: here's a good way to do the above: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html

Comment: amazing.  I was struggling with rewriting my html for a while.  thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to look at the `event` object passed into the click handler and see what type it is. Look at the [Event.Type](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.target) documentation for more information.

```
function handler(event) {
  var $target = $(event.target);
  if( $target.is("li") ) {
    $target.children().toggle();
  }
}

$("ul").click(handler).find("li > ").h
```

***Note: Code copied from linked URL.***

Comment: This answer is especially useful since it works even when the event is bound using the `.live()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try a simple `return;`